# SVG file changes every 1 sec

Tags: svg

I'm very new to HTML, SVG, javascript and all what is web programming.

I need to do a synoptic webpage to display different information's on my data acquisition.

I have a python script which read data from physical devices and I'd like to update these acquisition on a web page.
My python script can change svg file fill color of different graphical components.

If , for example, this is my svg file:

```
<svg width="800" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="Layer_1">
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect id="svg_1" height="386" width="527" y="94" x="150" stroke="#231F20" fill="yellow"/>
  <rect id="svg_2" height="386" width="527" y="114" x="450" stroke="#231F20" fill="yellow"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

My python script change id="svg_1" or id="svg_2" fill attribute and the file is displayed in this simple html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HTML SVG</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Design</h1>
          <img id="demo" alt="" height="600" onload="javascript:(function()

{setTimeout(function(
{document.getElementById('demo').src=document.getElementById('demo').src.split('?'
[0]+'?time='+new Date().getTime();},1000);}())" src="ee.svg" width="800" />
</body>
</html>
```

the javascript code refreshes svg file every 1 sec.

This simple solution works for few minutes...then the svg file is not anymore displayed...

Any help?
Thanks,
Marcin

Comment: Race condition maybe? If python has written a partial file when the refresh happens then the document may error.

Comment: The query string/the time stamp -- is it only used for requesting a new/fresh URL, but the server response is the same OR will the query string be used on the server for creating the response. In the later case, maybe the server time is a bit behind, so it has nothing to return. Can you see in the browser dev tools if the response from the server is 200 OK and has content?

Answer (score 0):

Polling is overkill; That is like checking your mailbox every minute for new email.

**your Server (Python) should send an Event to all (listening) Clients, on every change**

The standard JavaScript [EventSource API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) was developed for that, [3 million years ago](https://caniuse.com/eventsource)
But Microsoft never implemented it in IE, so ahem.. older.. developers reach for WebRTC too often.

For Python code see: [Medium.com: Python generator and Server Sent Events](https://medium.com/code-zen/python-generator-and-html-server-sent-events-3cdf14140e56)

Code should look ***something*** like:

##### Backend:

```py
@route("/stream")
def stream():
    def eventStream():
        while True:
            # Poll data from the database
            # and see if there's a new message
            if len(messages) > len(previous_messages):
                yield "data: 
                    {}\n\n".format(messages[len(messages)-1)])"
    
    return Response(eventStream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

##### Front-end:

```
let eventSource = new EventSource("/stream");
eventSource.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.warn(e.detail);
  // Yeah, the server sent something!
};
```

**Note:** There aren't that many good blogs on SSE (Server Sent Events), because B[mmmm] Microsoft never implemented it in IE, Microsoft Edge (on Chromium) runs a-okay.

For PHP backend see: https://kevinchoppin.dev/blog/server-sent-events-in-php

Comment: thanks!But, unfortunately, from the web server I can only access a folder...and that's why I was thinking to modify the svg file...